# Trouble with method to compute covariance

Tags: probability

Lets say we have 6 players, each player play 6 games. 
Each player win a game in probability of 0.2 and loose in probability of 0.8.
for each win the player get 1 point.

let $Y$ be the random variable that is the sum, of the number of points, of all the 6 players toghter.
let $X$ be the random variable that count how many players won at least 1 game (from 6).
I need to  calculate $COV(X,Y)$

I want to use $COV(X,Y) = COV(X, E(Y|X))$ 
can I say that  $E(Y|X) = E(X+(Bin(5X,0.2)) = E(X)+X$

My logic is that if we know that X players won at least one game, then we have $X$ points that we know the players recive + $5X$ games that we dont know the score of them.
(as well, we have $(6-X)6$ we know the players lost)

and then $COV(X,Y) = COV(X,E(X|Y)) = COV (X, E(X)+X) = COV(X,X) = V(X)$

I know that this way is not right, and I also know a diffrent way to slove this question.
Please help me understant why the described way isn't good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I say that  $E(Y|X) = E(X+(Bin(5X,0.2)) = E(X)+X$ [?]

No.

> Please help me understan[d] why the described way isn't good.

The reasoning you describe assumes that, if the distribution of $\xi$ is Bin$(6,x)$  (with $x=0.2$) then the distribution of $\xi-1$ conditioned by $\xi\geqslant1$ is Bin$(5,x)$, which is not true.

To wit, for every $0\leqslant k\leqslant5$, $P[\xi=k+1\mid\xi\geqslant1]$ is proportional to ${6\choose k+1}x^{k+1}(1-x)^{5-x}$, where the constant of proportionality does not depend on $k$. Likewise, if the distribution of $\eta$ is Bin$(5,x)$, then $P[\eta=k]={5\choose k}x^{k}(1-x)^{5-x}$ for every $0\leqslant k\leqslant5$. These coincide if and only if ${6\choose k+1}$ and ${5\choose k}$ are proportional. Their ratio being $\frac6{k+1}$, which depends on $k$, this is not so.